# Auto complete text view is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

Auto complete text view is not working in android version 2.3

Iam developing an app in which i uses an Auto complete Text view

The auto complete works fine when tested it with Android 4.0

But when iam using Android 2.3 the auto complete drop down is not showing
More over any text entered in it also not visible

My code is given below

In onCreate

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemClass);
className.setAdapter(adapter);
className.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: not working means what?? show your logcat.

Comment: Need more code.. className definition and itemClass definitions..

Comment: not working means ->Auto complete text view is not working in android version 2.3

Iam developing an app in which i uses an Auto complete Text view

The auto complete works fine when tested it with Android 4.0

But when iam using Android 2.3 the auto complete drop down is not showing @segi

Comment: @blganesh101 The auto complete works fine when tested it with Android 4.0

But when iam using Android 2.3 the auto complete drop down is not showing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link solved my issue pls have a try

1. by using sqlite db

   http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-use-autocomplete-searchbox-in.html

the source code can be downloaded from

```
 http://media0.webgarden.com/files/media0:4e0f5e93920fd.rar.upl/AutoCompleteSample.rar
```

2.non dynamic

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

    public class Autocomplete extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        String[] names = 
        {
        "vasu","kamal","vimal","santhosh",
        "prabu","prakash",
        "bala","baskar",
        "arjun","aravind",
        "shankar","siva",
        "mani","manickam",
        "mohan",
        "eswar",
        "vikram",
        };
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,names);
            MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.books);
            //AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.books);
            //textView.setThreshold(1);
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);
            textView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
            //acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Source can be downloaded from

```
http://media0.webgarden.com/files/media0:4dd6666334cb7.rar.upl/Autocomplete.rar
```

First of all import this as a project and test in both device then try to integrate this with your app